# Notifications script, how to put data inside of a div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, notifications

I was trying to create a notifications system for a website with the following code :

```
setInterval(function() {
$.post('notifications.php', {

    email: 123

}, function(data) {


});
}, 30000);
```

And the notifications.php :

```
$userid = $_SESSION[username];
$notifications = array();
$sql = "SELECT appreciation FROM ms_notifications WHERE email = '$userid' AND new = '1'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($res)) {
while ($r = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $notifications[] = $r->appreciation;
}
$nb_result = mysql_num_rows($res);
}
$sql = "UPDATE ms_notifications SET new = '0' WHERE email = '$userid'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

echo $nb_result;
```

Problem is that, as I'm new to jquery/Js, I don't know how to put the result inside of a div. For now it stays on the top of the page, above everything.
I tried that, inside the data function but not working... :

```
$('#test_app').html(data);
```

I guess it's a very stupid question but help would be really appreciated ! Thank you very much.

UPDATE : Here the HTML Code

```
 <?php 
  session_start();
 include ('connection/database.php');
 include ('login_script.php');
 include ('notifications.php');


 if($logged_in){
 ?>


 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Home</title>
</head>

<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ms.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="js/font_i/specimen_files/easytabs.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<!-- FONT SCRIPT--> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#container').easyTabs({defaultContent:1});
    });
</script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var scrollSpeed = 70;       // Speed in milliseconds
var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
var current = 0;            // The current pixel row
var imageHeight = 505;     // Background image height
var headerHeight = 59;     // How tall the header is.

  //The pixel row where to start a new loop
  var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

 function scrollBg(){

//Go to next pixel row.
current -= step;

//If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
if (current == restartPosition){
    current = 0;
}

//Set the CSS of the header.
$('#main_logo').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");


}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed)  

</script> 

<!-- NOTIFICATIONS_SCRIPT !!!!!! -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

setInterval(function() {

$.post('notifications.php', {

    email: 123

}, function(data) {


 });
 }, 30000);

 </script>


<style>
body{
font-family:SommetRoundedLight;
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="header_contain">
   <div id="test_app">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>

 <?php  }
 else{
       echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 window.location.replace("connexion.php");
 -->
 </script>'; 

  } ?>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Can you post your html too please?

Comment: Probably it has something to do with your mark up, so it would help if you could post it here aswell.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I Updated the post with the HTML

Comment: So when you added this code $('#test_app').html(data); to function(data) and the data showed at the top of the page, what were you expecting/wanting to happen?

Comment: I was expecting the data to appear inside the test_app div, inside the page content, not on the very top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.append()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: Thank you for answering! Result is still at the top of the page, above div#container. But now I have an error happening after 30 sec (when script check if there are new notifications) saying "no database selected". Which is strange as result on top show the right number of new notifications in the db...

Comment: You need to update your php code to select the DB table first of all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('#test_app').html(data);
```

just use:

```
$('#test_app').html('<div>' + data + '</div>');
```

Seems to simple to be it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you, now it's displaying on #test_app. But only once the script looks for the server the second time. The first time, it displays only on top, not in #test_app. What am I doing wrong :/

Comment: In fact, now it's updating in #test_app but stay on the first value above everything...